# Trying to build a json file but JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end) is raised when reading it

Tags: python, json

**RESOLVED**

I'm trying to load a json file in python via:

```
json_file = open('bill_history.json', "r+")
bill_history = json.load(json_file)
```

However, I'm being met with the following exception:

```
raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 13 (char 12)
```

I've read that `json.load` can only read one json object per line and this exception is thrown when there is more than one json object in a line. I don't beleive I have more than one json object in my line. I'm confused, maybe this has something to do with how I'm nesting dictionaries? Have I formatted my json file incorrectly?

bill_history.json:

```
{
    "months": [
        {
            "month": "September",
            "is_paid": "False",
            "utilities": [
                {
                    "utility": "electricity",
                    "is_paid": "False",
                    "bill": "-1",
                    "paid": "0",
                    "resident_payments": [
                        {
                            "resident": "A",
                            "has_paid": "False",
                            "cost": -1,
                            "paid": 0
                        },
                        {
                            "resident": "B",
                            "has_paid": "False",
                            "cost": -1,
                            "paid": 0
                        },
                        {
                            "resident": "C",
                            "has_paid": "False",
                            "cost": -1,
                            "paid": 0
                        },
                        {
                            "resident": "D",
                            "has_paid": "False",
                            "cost": -1,
                            "paid": 0
                        },
                        {
                            "resident": "E",
                            "has_paid": "False",
                            "cost": -1,
                            "paid": 0
                        },
                        {
                            "resident": "F",
                            "has_paid": "False",
                            "cost": -1,
                            "paid": 0
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**FIX:**

use `json.loads`:

```
json_file = open('bill_history.json', "r+")
json_string = json_file.read()
bill_history = json.loads(json_string)
```

Comment: I tried exact same and it works for me ! I doubt while saving you have inserted extra characters in the file. Please check. Also my python version is 3.9.1

Comment: @anand thanks for responding. I've double-checked that I have not added any characters anywhere and the post above matches my current file. Still raising the same error. I'll try updating my version of python and get back to you if it works or not.

Comment: Updating to 3.9.6 did not solve the issue.

Comment: Your json is fine and you can always check your json structure here - https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: @softsun2 I cant reproduce the problem with the json you have posted.  `import json
with open('bill_history.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)` just works...